Is this LTL formula really valid?
Fp → (¬p U p)
What if I have a transition system in which p is always true? Then Fp would be valid but not (¬p U p), right?
This formula is claimed to be valid in my study litterature, what have I misunderstood here?

The formula $\phi \mathrm{U} \psi$ is satisfied if $\psi$ is true right now. If we express it as "eventually $\psi$ becomes true and until then $\phi$ holds", it is important to remember that the waiting period may consist of zero steps at all.
So in $\neg p \mathrm{U} p$, the requirement that $\neg p$ is true until $p$ becomes true is trivially satisfied. This means that $\neg p \mathrm{U} p$ is actually equivalent to $\mathrm{F} p$ (and this is how we see that we can define $\mathrm{F}$ in terms of $\mathrm{U}$).

I don't see what this answer adds to the already existing answer.

@BaderAbuRadi Your answer is too formal for my taste. It proves, but it doesn't explain.


Which part do you think is not explained?
As far as I see, you wrote the basic definition, which you call too formal, in words.
I added explanations explicitly in addition to the formal definition: "In words, ...". So I fail to see what my answer does not explain, and what value your answer adds.


Consider a computation $\pi = \sigma_1, \sigma_2, \ldots$ over $2^{AP}$. For $j\geq 1$, let $\pi^j$ denote the suffix $\sigma_j, \sigma_{j+1}, \ldots$ of $\pi$. Then, the semantics of the $U$ operator is defined as follows:

$\pi \vDash \Psi _1 U \Psi_2$ iff there exists $k\geq 1$ such that $\pi^k \vDash \Psi_2$ and $\pi^i \vDash \Psi_1$ for all $1\leq i < k$.

In particular, when $k = 1$, then $\pi^i \vDash \Psi_1$ holds vacuously for all $1\leq i < k$  as there are no $i$'s with $1\leq i < k$.
The formula $Fp \to (\neg p U p)$ is equivalent to the formula $(\neg Fp) \lor (\neg p U p)$. In words, it specifies that  $p$ does not hold in the computation, or  $p$ eventually holds in some position, and does not hold before that position. It is not hard to show that $\pi \vDash Fp \to (\neg p U p)$ for every computation $\pi$.
What you missed is that in a computation that satisfies $(\neg p U p)$ it could be the case that $\neg p$ holds vacuously.
